# Oracle: select from view, but where clause value from target table

Tags: sql, oracle

TARGET_TABLE:

```
id   | col1 
------------
1      'mySample1234'
2      'mySample3456'
```

Current sql of MY_VEIW:

```
select substr(col1,-4,4) from TARGET_TABLE;
```

My query:

```
select * from MY_VEIW where col1 = 'mySample1234';
```

My result:

```
Empty
```

Expected result:

```
id   | col1
------------
1      '1234'
```

In other words, I want to select by 'value of TARGET_TABLE', despite of 'filtered value of MY_VIEW'.

**How to achieve that?**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Regexp_replace`

```
select regexp_replace(col1 , '[A-Za-z]') 
From TARGET_TABLE
```

Comment: ?? What does this do? How is it related to the question asked?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand... Do you have a column named col1 in your base table, then you extract the last four characters, put them in a column also named col1 in the view, and then you want to select from the view?

If so - I understand how '1234' is the last four characters of 'mySample1234'. The full string is in the base table, and '1234' is in the view. How do you expect '1234' = 'mySample1234' to return anything but false? col1 in MY_VIEW is just '1234', not the full original string.

To return rows from MY_VIEW, you must filter with `WHERE col1 = '1234'` Or, if you were trying to see if the last four characters of col1 in TARGET_TABLE match the last four characters of a longer string, you could use `WHERE col1 = SUBSTR('mySample1234', -4)` (or any other comparison string in SUBSTR).

**ADDED**:  If you are trying to match col1 in MY_VIEW with the corresponding col1 in TARGET_TABLE, for example in a join, you can write it like this:

```
ON  (or WHERE ...)   MY_VIEW.col1 = SUBSTR(TARGET_TABLE.col1, -4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use two arguments:

```
select substr(col1, -4)
from TARGET_TABLE;
```

However, if this isn't working:

```
select * from MY_VEIW where col1 = 'mySample1234';
```

Then the reason is that `col1` is in the underlying *table* not the view.  I think you want:

```
create view my_view as
    select col1, substr(col1, -4) as last4
    from TARGET_TABLE;
```

Then you can use:

```
select *
from MY_VEIW
where col1 = 'mySample1234';
```

Or:

```
select *
from MY_VEIW
where last4 = '1234';
```

Comment: Assume data 'mySample1234' is secured. I am not allowed to get full value. ))

Comment: @SparX . . . If you cannot get the full value, then you cannot use it in a `where` clause.  For a real problem such as credit card numbers, you would simply hash the number and use that for comparisons in all systems.

Comment: Can u give more info?

Comment: Yes, it is kind of 'super secret number'.

Comment: @SparX - Did you understand Gordon's very first point? In the expression substr(col1, -4, 4), the third argument (4) tells you how far you want to read. If the third argument is not given, substr will read through the end of the input string - which is exactly what you want. Your expression is CORRECT, not wrong, but you can simplify it to just substr(col1, -4).

Comment: I know, I offered an answer to what I thought you may be asking.